# Can I have a parent element's style override a child's with Sass?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a table where a CSS class is added when a row or column meets a condition. The class for the row (technically cell) element `<td>` overrides the column element `<tr>`.

This is the generated HTML

```
 <table>
    <tr data-v-5cc42bfc="" item-index="1" render="true" class="row-title-1">
      <td data-v-5cc42bfc="">Ahmad Ortiz Jr.</td>

      <td data-v-5cc42bfc="" class="center aligned column-total">lkulas@example.com</td>

      <td data-v-5cc42bfc="">1</td>

      <td data-v-5cc42bfc="">1992-09-12 00:00:00</td>

      <td data-v-5cc42bfc="">in</td>

      <td data-v-5cc42bfc="">F</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

The SCSS code

```
.column-total {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.row-title-1 {
  background-color: #699dcd;
}
```

And the complete reproducible example at https://codepen.io/hanxue/pen/GxwXdG

The column style will override the row style

[image: Table result]

#### Workaround

It is possible to solve the problem by having more specific styling, for example:

```
.row-title-1 {
  background-color: #699dcd;
  .column-total {
    background-color: #699dcd;
  }
}
.row-title-2 {
  background-color: #89b2d8;
  .column-total {
    background-color: #699dcd;
  }
}
.row-title-3 {
  background-color: #a1c7e4;
  .column-total {
    background-color: #699dcd;
  }
}
.column-total {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

The problem is this approach is not scalable and gets convoluted quickly as the number of row and column styles increases.

### Question

Is there any way for a parent element's style to override its child element?

Comment: to be clear, this is not override .. but the background of td is above the background of tr which is different and change the meaning of your question

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, the problem is not a problem of overriding but the background of cell element (`td`) is above the background of `tr` element. Here is an example to confirm this by using linear-gradient as background of `td`

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
 padding:20px;
}
.color-tr {
 background:red;
}
.color-td {
 background:linear-gradient(blue,transparent);
}
```

```html
we can see the red behind the gradient so there is no override
<table>
  <tr class="color-tr">
    <td class="color-td">aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To avoid such thing you can use custom properties (CSS variables) and consider setting the default value the color you want to apply on the `td`. Since custom properties are inherited, you simply need to speficy it within the `tr` and it will be used within the `td` instead of the default one.

Here is an example:

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  background:#ccc;
}
td {
 padding:20px;
 color:#fff;
}
.color-tr1 {
 --c:blue;
 background:var(--c);
}
.color-tr2 {
 --c:black;
 background:var(--c);
}
.color-td1 {
  background:var(--c,red);
}
.color-td2 {
  background:var(--c,pink);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="color-tr1">
    <td class="color-td1">With color</td>
    <td>no color</td>
    <td>no color</td>
    <td>no color</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td class="color-td1">With color</td>
    <td>no color</td>
    <td class="color-td2">With color</td>
    <td>no color</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td class="color-td1">With color</td>
    <td>no color</td>
    <td>no color</td>
    <td class="color-td2">With color</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="color-tr1">
    <td class="color-td2">With color</td>
    <td>no color</td>
    <td>no color</td>
    <td class="color-td1">With color</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, when you define a background-color to the `tr` we will setup a custom property that will **override** the default one used with the `td`; thus the `td` will have the same background.